# Need help on an ER Diagram for a “Wireless Internet Service Provider”

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship, diagram

I have this diagram.

[Diagram (1/2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJteG.png)

[Diagram (2/2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y13IL.png)

Just in case : Equipo (Device), Servicio (Service) , Categoria(Category), Persona (Person), Comprobante (Voucher,Receipt)

I need to be able to do the following:

"Cuando un cliente informa de un equipo al cual se le suministrará alguno de los
servicios es necesario llevar registro de su fecha de alta, como también su fecha de baja si la hubiere.(Whenever a client informs of a device which is going to be given a service, it is needed to register the activation date and the deactivation date if there is one)
The first thing I tought was to just add attributes to the service table, for example ( act_date timestamp and dea_date timestamp), would that be okey ? Or maybe create another table, like the one that says "Categoria"(Category), but to save those dates. Any ideas ?

Thank you.